# Perl: for (min .. max) uses random order, but I want it in order 0,1,2,

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, perl, for-loop

As I am a total beginner to perl, oracle sql and everything else. I have to write a script to parse an excel file and write the values into an oracle sql database.

Everything is good so far. But it writes the rows in random order into the database.

```
for ($row_min .. $row_max) {...insert into db code $sheetValues[$_][col0] etc...}
```

I don't get it why the rows are inserted in a random order?
And obviously how can I get them in order? `excel_row 0 => db_row 0` and so on...

The values in the array are in order! The number of rows is dynamic.

Thanks for your help, I hope you got all the information you need.

Edit:

```
&parseWrite;

sub parseWrite {
    my @sheetValues;
    my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet(0);
    my ($row_min, $row_max) = $worksheet->row_range();
    print "| Zeile $row_min bis $row_max |";
    my ($col_min, $col_max) = $worksheet->col_range();
    print " Spalte $col_min bis $col_max |<br>";

    for my $row ($row_min .. $row_max) {
        for my $col ($col_min .. $col_max) {
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell ($row,$col);
            next unless $cell;
            $sheetValues[$row][$col] = $cell->value();
            print $sheetValues[$row][$col] .
               "(".$row.","        .$col.")"."<br>";
        }
    }

    for ($row_min .. $row_max) {
        my $sql="INSERT INTO t_excel (
          a,b,c,d,e
        ) VALUES (
          '$sheetValues[$_][0 ]',
          '$sheetValues[$_][1 ]',
          '$sheetValues[$_][2 ]',
          '$sheetValues[$_][3 ]',
          '$sheetValues[$_][4 ]',
          '$sheetValues[$_][5 ]'
        )";
        $dbh->do($sql);
    }
}
```

With in order I mean that my PL/SQL Developer 8.0.3 (given by my company)

shows with `SELECT * FROM t_excel;`

*pic*

But `shell = (2,0), maggie = (0,0) and 13 = (1,0)` in the array.

Comment: `row_min` is not a variable name, unless you foolishly are using barewords. Show the real code you are using, this is not useful information. Also how you assign to the min and max.

Comment: What do you mean by "random order"? Oracle won't guarantee the order in which results are returned unless there is an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't provide enough information, I edited it and hope that it's better now.

Comment: How are you checking that its inserting into oracle in a random order?

Comment: SELECT * FROM t_excel in the PL/SQL Developer.
Or is this no reliable information whether it is in order or not?
As David Faber states?

Comment: @DragooNick Perhaps you should order the query: E.g. `SELECT * FROM t_excel ORDER BY id ASC` (Or use whatever column you want to order by, if there is no `id` column)

Comment: Using `$dbh->do` with interpolated variables is asking for trouble. You are vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use placeholders and `$sth->execute` instead. See the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks TLP! I'll try to change that part!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rows are being inserted in the order you expect.  I believe the mistaken assumption here is that SELECT will return rows in the same order they're inserted.  This is not true.  While implementations may make it seem like it does, *SELECT has no default order*.  You're thinking a table is basically like a big list, INSERT is adding to the end of it, and SELECT just iterates through it.  That's not a bad approximation, but it can lead you to make bad assumptions.  The reality is that you can say little for sure about how a table is stored.

SQL is a [declarative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) which means you tell the computer *what you want*.  This is different from a most other language types where you tell the computer *what to do*.  `SELECT * FROM sometable` says "give me all the rows and all their columns in the table".  Since you didn't give an order, the database can return them in whatever order it likes.  Contrast with the procedural meaning which would be "iterate through all the rows in the table" as if the table was some sort of list.

Most languages encourage you to take advantage of how data is stored.  Declarative languages prevent you from knowing how data is stored.

If you want your SELECT to be ordered, you have to give it an [ORDER BY](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-order-by-sql-tutorial/).

Comment: Thank you very much :) I got confused by the task I got from my boss and didn't know this.